# Middleware for per-request data

Tags: haskell, clojure, haskell-wai

In `clojure`, I can write something like this:

```
(defn wrap-my-header
  [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (let [request (if (get-in request [:headers "my-header"])
                    (assoc request :has-my-header? true)
                    request)]
      (handler request))))
```

In this middleware, I'm checking if I have a non-nil value in `my-header` in `:headers`, if yes, I'll attach some data in the `request` map. This demonstrates that I can treat `request` and `response` as a somewhat "stateful" data.

I'm still new in haskell and wanted to do similar things with `scotty`. After looking at the type of [middleware](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.2/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Middleware), I can create a middleware like this:

```
myMiddleware :: Middleware 
myMiddleware app req respond = app req respond
```

After staring at the type for a long time, I still don't know  how to do it. Some reading and thinking makes me assume that this is not possible, `Middleware` can only only short-circuit the handler and/or alter the generated response. Is this true?

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This confused me for a long time too! But figuring it out gave me a helpful technique for understanding Haskell library types.

First I'll start with my middleware being undefined:

```
myMiddleware :: Middleware
myMiddleware = undefined
```

So what is `Middleware`? The key is to look at the [definition of the type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.2/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Middleware):

```
type Middleware = Application -> Application
```

Let's start at the first layer (or level of abstraction) by having the middleware take an Application and return an Application. We don't know how to modify an application, so we'll return exactly what's passed in for now.

```
myMiddleware :: Application -> Application
myMiddleware theOriginalApp = theOriginalApp
```

But what is an Application? Again, let's [turn to Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.2/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application):

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

An Application is a function! We may not know exactly what each part is supposed to do or be, but we can find out. Let's replace `Application` in our type signature with the function type:

```
myMiddleware :: (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived) 
             -> (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived)
myMiddleware theOriginalApp = theOriginalApp
```

Now we can see this type should allow us to access a `Request`! But how do we use it?

We can expand `theOriginalApp` in the function definition into a lambda expression that matches the return type:

```
myMiddleware :: (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived) 
             -> (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived)
myMiddleware theOriginalApp = (\req sendResponse -> undefined)
```

We can do whatever we want with the request now:

```
myMiddleware :: (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived) 
             -> (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived)
myMiddleware theOriginalApp = (\req sendResponse ->
  let myModifiedRequest = addSomeHeadersIfMissing req in
    undefined)
```

Now what about that `undefined`? Well, we're trying to match our lambda to the type of that return function, which takes a Request and a function (that we don't care about) and returns an `IO ResponseReceived`.

So, we need something that can use `myModifiedRequest` and return an `IO ResponseReceived`. Luckily our type signature indicates that `theOriginalApp` has the right type! To make it fit, we only need to give it the `sendResponse` function too.

```
myMiddleware :: (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived) 
             -> (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived)
myMiddleware theOriginalApp = (\req sendResponse ->
  let myModifiedRequest = addSomeHeadersIfMissing req in
    theOriginalApp myModifiedRequest sendResponse)
```

And that's it, that will work! We can improve the readability by simplifying the type annotation back to `Middleware`, and getting rid of the lambda. (We can also [eta-reduce](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) and remove the `sendResponse` term from both the arguments and the definition, but I think it's clearer if it stays.)

The result:

```
myMiddleware :: Middleware
myMiddleware theOriginalApp req sendResponse =
  let myModifiedRequest = addSomeHeadersIfMissing req in
    theOriginalApp myModifiedRequest sendResponse
```